# how to add a chinese domain name into a Windows hosts file ?

Tags: windows, hosts

lets say I have a domain `我等主营.com` that I want to add it into Windows hosts file for development purposes as below:

```
127.0.0.1         www我等主营.com
```

I could save the modification with Notepad++ but when puting the name on a web browser www.我等主营.com, it does not go to 127.0.0.1 but instead it resolves to the domain's public IP or whatever it is. It works fine for me with English domain names. How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are required to convert the 我等主菅.com into punycode representation in the hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1    xn--tiq769bnnsi9h.com
```